# Modifying Image using PHP and sending it to browser

Tags: php, image

I would appreciate your thoughts on this method.

I have a page that uploads a pic given by user and displays it after saving it in a database now that's very simple so, I wanted users to be able to modify these images as they wish, hence I decided to add filters to these images using php. Now before these images are uploaded to the database I want the user to see a preview of what the image looked like after adding the filter.

The solution I came up was to send the image to php file using a form and AJAX using POST, do all necessary checks if file was safe. create a new image and add filter and then convert it to base 64 and send it back to browser and display it using a DATA URL

something like:

```
   <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4/8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot">
```

Is this a good idea or there is something I should worry about?

Comment: its not good idea to save images on the database, after a few months it will be super heavy and slow. upload it to a folder and always save the original and the recent modified version in case you want to offer the original to your user. and still can modify it via Javascript.

Comment: @eddwinpaz In some special circumstances it can be okay... you just have to know what you're getting into, and weigh the pros/cons.  For instance, GridFS on top of MongoDB works quite well for replicating files and file-like binary objects between servers.  Of course, you wouldn't mix your regular data in with it...

Comment: @addwhinpaz ofcourse I know that ..when I say save in database I did not mean the actual image :)

Answer (score 1):

Base-64 encoding adds about 33% overhead.  For this reason, it is usually preferable to serve the image in binary form.

You can do this with a PHP script easily.

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo $yourImageData;
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<img src="yourPHPScript.php?id=12345" />
```

Comment: thanks for the reply Brad. I'll find more about this

Answer (score 0):

hello we have a library for that actually, we make use of GD library to be able to achieve the correct image output that we would like to have, you can check more about our image library here.. by the way, our library does not only contain image library.. it has a bunch of useful libraries that you can actually use on your projects and we opensource it
http://eden.openovate.com/documentation/core/images